# Finding ordered pairs $(a,b)$ which are positive integers for $\sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}}=a\cos\frac {\pi}b$

Tags: trigonometry

> Finding ordered pairs $(a,b)$ for $\sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}}=a\cos\frac {\pi}b$

I did:

$768=2^8\cdot 3$
So:
$$\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}=\sqrt{32+2\sqrt{2^6\cdot3}}=\sqrt{8}+\sqrt{24}$$
Now:
$$\sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}}=\sqrt{8+2\sqrt2+2\sqrt6}=?$$

Comment: Hello,what is $a,b$?

Comment: @math110 positive integers

Comment: @math110 why not

Comment: $(a,b) = (4,24)$

Comment: @achillehui hit&trial??

Comment: @ADG In order for this to have an answer of reasonable size, one should be able to simplify $(a\cos\frac{\pi}{b})^2 - 8$ somehow. The suggests $a = 4$ and one can determine $b$ numerically. The rest is convert this ansatz into a real answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}}$$
$$ \sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+16\sqrt{3}}}$$ 
$$ \sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+32\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})}}$$ 
$$ \sqrt{8+4\sqrt{2+2\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})}} $$
$$ \sqrt{8+8\cos(\frac{\pi}{12})} $$
$$ 4\cos(\frac{\pi}{24}) $$

Comment: long time no see

Answer (score 2):

Notice 
$$a\cos\frac{\pi}{b} = \sqrt{8 + \sqrt{32 + \sqrt{768}}}
\quad\implies\quad a^2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{b} - 8 = \sqrt{32 + \sqrt{768}}$$

In order for the equation on the left to have an answer of reasonable size, we should be able to simplify the expression $a^2\cos^2\frac{\pi}{b} - 8$ somehow. This strongly suggest we pick $a = 4$
as an ansatz. Assume $a = 4$, we get

$$\begin{align}
& 8\cos\frac{2\pi}{b} = 16\cos^2\frac{\pi}{b} - 8 =
\sqrt{32 + \sqrt{768}}\\
\implies &
\cos\frac{2\pi}{b} = \sqrt{\frac12 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}}\\
\implies &\cos\frac{4\pi}{b} = 2\cos^2\frac{2\pi}{b} - 1 = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos\frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align}
$$

This suggest $(a,b) = (4,24)$ can be a solution of the original problem. This can be verified by comparing the numerical values of $\;4\cos\frac{\pi}{24}\;$ and $\;\sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}}\;$ and using the fact both of them are roots of the same algebraic equation whose roots are simple.

$$((u^2-8)^2-32)^2-768 = 0$$

If we restrict $a$ to $4$, there are no other solutions for $b$. 
Otherwise, we have

$$\cos\frac{4\pi}{b} = \cos\frac{\pi}{6}
\quad\leadsto\quad \frac{4\pi}{b} \ge \frac{11\pi}{6}
\quad\leadsto\quad b \le \frac{24}{11}
\quad\leadsto\quad b = 1
$$
and $b = 1$ is clearly not a solution!

Comment: do you think there are other solutions?

Comment: @ADG when $a = 4$, there are no other solution for $b$. I suspect  there are no other solutions in general but I don't have a proof.